# How to achieve python's any() with a custom predicate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming, any, filterfunction

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> if filter(lambda x: x > 10, l):
...     print "foo"
... else:                     # the list will be empty, so bar will be printed
...     print "bar"
... 
bar
```

I'd like to use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) for this instead, but `any()` only takes one argument: the iterable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) as that one argument:

```
any(x > 10 for x in l)
```

Here the predicate is in the expression side of the generator expression, but you can use any expression there, including using functions.

Demo:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> any(x > 10 for x in l)
False
>>> l = range(20)
>>> any(x > 10 for x in l)
True
```

The generator expression will be iterated over *until* `any()` finds a `True` result, and no further:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> endless_counter = count()
>>> any(x > 10 for x in endless_counter)
True
>>> # endless_counter last yielded 11, the first value over 10:
...
>>> next(endless_counter)
12
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a generator expression inside of `any()`:

```
pred = lambda x: x > 10
if any(pred(i) for i in l):
    print "foo"
else:
    print "bar"
```

This assumes you already have some predicate function you want to use, of course if it is something simple like this you can just use the Boolean expression directly: `any(i > 10 for i in l)`.